# How To Make User Profile In Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

How To Make User Profile in Django?

Hi I Want to Know How To Make User Profile when user signup in our django app i want create a profile page for the person

Here is my **Views.py**

```
 def user_reg(request):
    register = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = user_register_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            register = True

            if register == True:
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/login")

        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = user_register_form()

    context = {'reg':form,}
    return render(request,'signup.html',context)
```

**Models.py**

```
class user_register_model(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    join_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

I Want To Know How To Create Profile Page If User sign Up in our website **Problem is How To Create His Profile Page**

For Example:

If You Register on Stack overflow You Click on profile icon and you can go to your page

Stack overflow Make Your Page

I Need Some Thing Like That

When User Signup i need user page but how to make that?

i research on google and youtube i can't find any prefect answer

can you please help me?

Comment: create "user registration" and " user dashboard". share the link of dashboard. Also, your should provide more detail about question if you want usable answer.

Comment: @sandeep i need to know how to create user profile page when user sign up

Comment: @sandeep question updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a URL in **urls.py** like this:

```
path('profile/<username>', views.user_profile, name='user_profile'),
```

**views.py** (If you are using **User** model to save user data.)

```
def user_profile(request, username):
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    context = {
       "user": user
    }


    return render(request, 'user_profile.html', context)
```

**user_profile.html** (use profile data as per requirement)

```
{{ user.username }}
{{ user.first_name }}
```

You can check this on link `http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/<username>/`. replace **username** with user's username and page will show data of only that user.

**-----------Edit-----------**

If you want to create link, use this:

```
<a class="nav-link navaour" href="{% url 'profile' username=<username> %}">
```

replace  user's username.

Comment: i get this error `Reverse for 'user_profile' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/(?P<username>[^/]+)$']`

Comment: did you pass "username" in url?

Comment: Yes I pass in url

Comment: but when i do that the use is login

Comment: Without password

Comment: Now I Get This Problem When i type for example `http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/test/` the user is login without password and username

Comment: 1 Last Thing If Insert this line `<li class="nav-item">

              <a class="nav-link navaour" href="{% url 'user_profile' %}"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>&nbsp; Sign up Free</a>
            </li>` in my `base.html` **i get this error** `Reverse for 'user_profile' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/(?P<username>[^/]+)$']`

Comment: NOW i get this error `Could not parse the remainder: '<username>' from '<username>'`

Comment: Code `<a class="nav-link navaour" href="{% url 'user_profile' username=<username> %}"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp; Profile</a>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202203/discussion-between-hamza-lachi-and-sandeep).

Comment: you have to replace <username> with username. if username is Hamza, link is {% url 'user_profile' username=Hamza %}. If you are passing user instance, use username=user.username.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a view with a template see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial03/#use-the-template-system). You can have editable forms or anything you like. This view will be shown only if the user is logged in and for unauthorized users redirect them to your login page.